# How to reorder wordpress main menu

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress, I have following customer menu on horizontal order as follows:
Comapany Info          Service Guide            Support         Others

I want to reorder them as follows:
Service Guide            Support         Comapany Info           Others

How can I do that? Note that - these are NOT menu item but menu itself.

Comment: "these are NOT menu item but menu itself" - WHAT?

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks more information. I assume you are:

a) trying to change the order of items in your menu, but as you stated "*these are NOT menu item but menu itself* - which means the menu items are hardcoded into the code. In this case try checking the header.php file of your theme and rearrange the items there. You should be able to find menu items there quite fast.

A small help - try creating [a child theme](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme/), so your edits will not get deleted with a new update of the theme.

b) trying to reorder menu items but you didn't know how to explain it in the question. Check under "Appearances" > "Menus" as it's most likely there and you just didn't open the right menu for the items to reorder.

Comment: Yes, I found that it was hard-coded and for that reason I wasn't able to reorder them from Appearance.